# Number of Retransmission in case of Go Back N

Tags: computer-networks

While Going through **Exercise problem** of " **Computer Networking**  A Top-Down Approach" by Kurose and Ross, i encountered this problem.I am giving my approach and the point where i am stuck at.

### Question

> Suppose Host A sends 5 data segments to Host B, and the 2nd segment
> (sent from A) is **lost**. In the end, all 5 data segments have been correctly
> received by Host B.How many segments has Host A sent in total and how many ACKs has Host B sent in total for **Go Back N**

#### Given Answer

> GoBackN:
> $A$ sends $9$ segments in total. They are initially sent segments $1, 2, 3, 4, 5 $and later resent segments $2, 3, 4, $and $5$. $B$ sends $8$ ACKs. They are $4$ ACKS with sequence number $1,$ and $4$ ACKS with sequence numbers $2, 3, 4,$ and $5.$

### My Approach /Doubt

I agree with the number of transmission of data segment by Host $A$.But i have doubt regarding **the Acknowledgement by Host $B$.**

#### Why?

> We know that GBN has sender side window size=$N$ while reciever side as only$1$ which is the reason that it cannot  recieve Out of order packet.

Now When Host $A$ sends entire packet $1,2,3,4,5$  where $2^{nd}$ gets lost then Host $B$ which is expecting Sequence number $1$.On recieving sequence number $1$, it will send ack as $2$i.e expecting sequence number $2$.As Sequence number gets lost , host $B$ will recieve sequence $3,4,5$ for which it will discard the packet as it is not the packet it is expecting.

On recieving again sequence number $2,3,4,5$(retransmitted packet), Host $B$ will send the Acknowledgement.

Total Acknowledgement i am getting is $5$ i.e ACk no for sequence number $1,2,3,4,5$ not $8$.

Please help me out where i am wrong ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GBN is resending ACK's for the discarded packets .

Excerpt from what I can find:

The receiver's actions in GBN are also simple. If a packet with sequence number n is received correctly and is in-order (i.e., the data last delivered to the upper layer came from a packet with sequence number n-1), the receiver sends an ACK for packet **n** and delivers the data portion of the packet to the upper layer. **In all other cases, the receiver discards the packet and resends an ACK for the most recently received in-order packet.** Note that since packets are delivered one-at-a-time to the upper layer, if packet k has been received and delivered, then all packets with a sequence number lower than k have also been delivered. Thus, the use of cumulative acknowledgements is a natural choice for GBN.